# Laravel: rewriting a function to allow orderBy

Tags: php, laravel

What would be the best way to rewrite this function to allow the orderBy to work within laravel? I have been unable to make this work:

```
$list = WatchlistModel::whereHas('show', function ($query) {

       $query->orderBy('title', 'asc');

})->where('user_id', $slug)->get();
```

To make more clarifications I have no idea why it's not working. right now im calling this with a foreach but when its outputted the orderby doesn't work. It orders by the "WatchlistModel's" id instead of the show's title within the query.

Comment: Why it's not working? Post what result do you get from this and describe what you expect.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code as it is. Your sorting WatchlistModel by relationship show. Why would you orderBy a table your not even retrieving?

Comment: @MwaaJoseph I currenlty have it set up as a one to many relationship, would you know how to retrieve the data from a one to many?

Comment: where would you like to retrieve data from? WatchlistModel or Show?